getting error when trying to add a forked repository's specific commit with yarn
I'm trying to use a forked repository in a react app which dependencies are managed by yarn.
When adding "@react-oauth/google": "git+https://github.com/thanhnh2-miichisoft/react-oauth.git#7f71538b0d79dbd46012aa593975f869c5bb8a28" which should be the correct format, to my package.json, I get this error
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @react-oauth/google@0.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.8.0".
warning " > @react-oauth/google@0.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.8.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > rollup-config-generator > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@7 || ^7.0.0-rc.2".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > @chakra-ui/icons@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=2.0.0-next.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > @chakra-ui/icons > @chakra-ui/icon@3.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=2.0.0-next.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > @emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.9.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > @emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.17.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
warning "workspace-aggregator-56dd2615-2828-4f58-bd57-479a5614108d > playground > @chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/modal > @chakra-ui/focus-lock > react-focus-lock@2.5.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
$ is-ci || husky install
husky - Git hooks installed
Done in 29.85s.

yarn pack v1.22.22
error Package doesn't have a version.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/pack for documentation about this command.

There is no package version here as I'm targeting a commit.
Any clue ?
Thanks
I tried adding the forked repository several ways, by adding it to my package.json file, or with the yarn add command. It looks like it's finding the repository, but this 'package error' is showing up, when it shouldn't.

The package.json of the git repo has no version field, and thus is not a valid package.json.
Seems like you need to depend on a sub-workspace of the repo instead. Unfortunately, Yarn v1 cannot specify a subdirectory of a GitHub repo as dependency, as far as I know.
